# SQL Query 'NOT IN'

Tags: sql

I need to create SQL Query:

List all customers who do not live in **Illinois (IL)**, **New York (NY)**, or **California (CA)**. Sort them by Postal Code in an ascending order. In the result table, show customer name, state, and postal code.

My Query is

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, STATE, POSTAL_CODE
FROM CUSTOMER_T
WHERE STATE NOT IN ('CA', 'FL', 'NJ')
GROUP BY POSTAL_CODE
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You just used `GROUP BY` instead of `ORDER BY`.

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the query return the wrong records or don't they get sorted? The latter is because you use Group by instead of Order By. If you don't get the right records, then you should check if your STATE field is properly defined instead of as varchar.

Comment: People have tried to guess what you're asking but it would be helpful to include in your question both the result you got _and_ the result you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, STATE, POSTAL_CODE 
FROM CUSTOMER_T 
WHERE STATE NOT IN ('CA', 'FL', 'NJ') 
Order BY POSTAL_CODE Asc
```

You don't need Group By Here. Replace Group By With Order By.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing mistake

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, STATE, POSTAL_CODE 
FROM CUSTOMER_T 
WHERE STATE NOT IN ('CA', 'IL', 'NY') 
                           ^     ^
Order BY POSTAL_CODE Asc
^
```